# Decoder java program to turn numbers into letters using a while loop

Tags: java

I am creating a decoder program that will essentially turn numbers into specific letters using a while loop but I'm having difficulties figuring out what's wrong with my code and also if there is a simpler way to put it using switch for example. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Decoder{
public static String decode(String str){
int i = 0;

while(i<str.length()){
  if(str.charAt(i)=='1')
    return("D");

  else if(str.charAt(i)=='2')
    return("W");

  else if(str.charAt(i)=='3')
    return("E");

  else if(str.charAt(i)=='4')
    return("L");

  else if(str.charAt(i)=='5')
    return("H");

  else if(str.charAt(i)=='6')
    return("O");

  else  if(str.charAt(i)=='7')
    return("R");

  return("Sorry, you must input numbers from 1-7 inclusive");
  }
i++;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("Enter a number ");
} 
}
```

Comment: do you even need that loop? why not use simple switch-case or mapping digits with letters?

Comment: `return` ... in a loop will break the loop. So you only check the first character (and you don't even call that function by the way)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Use a constant char array as a lookup table.

At index 0, store 'D'. At index 1, store 'W', etc.

Whenever you encounter a number in the source, subtract '1' to it to get the index in the array for this number, and get the matching letter from the array.

The code is left as an exercise.

Comment: @userunknown how would that be simpler? The character '1' doesn't have the numeric value 1. So a subtraction would still be needed.

Comment: If we want to "improve" the mapping, using a `Map<String, String>` or `Character` would be better but here with only numeric value, this works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the array mentioned by JB Nizet, you could try:

- `switch` statement
- a `Map<Integer, String>` containing the digit/letter pairs

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder and switch/case like that:

```
public class Decoder {
public static String decode(String str) {
    int i = 0;
    StringBuilder decodedString = new StringBuilder();

    while (i < str.length()) {
        switch (str.charAt(i)) {
        case '1':
            decodedString.append("D");
            break;
        case '2':
            decodedString.append("W");
            break;
        case '3':
            decodedString.append("E");
            break;
        case '4':
            decodedString.append("L");
            break;
        case '5':
            decodedString.append("H");
            break;
        case '6':
            decodedString.append("O");
            break;
        case '7':
            decodedString.append("R");
            break;
        default:
            return ("Sorry, you must input numbers from 1-7 inclusive");
        }
        i++;
    }

    return decodedString.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(decode(input.next()));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```